# Desktop.getDesktop().isSupported(Desktop.Action.OPEN) returns true but then Desktop#open(java.io.File) throws "IOException: Failed to show URI"

Tags: java, desktop, ioexception, gnome-3

In java I'm trying to open a file using Desktop.getDesktop().open(File file) but it throws IOException although Desktop.getDesktop().isSupported(Desktop.Action.OPEN) says the action is supported. 
I'm using Gnome version: Version: 3.22.3-3.

The code snippet:

```
    Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
    if (desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.OPEN))
        desktop.open(file);
```

Does anybody know why

> desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.OPEN)

returns true?
I know I could use "xdg-open" to open the file but I would like to understand what is happening here.

Thanks in advance!

**update:** the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to show URI:file:/home/TEST_FILES/blabla.xls
at sun.awt.X11.XDesktopPeer.launch(XDesktopPeer.java:121)
at sun.awt.X11.XDesktopPeer.open(XDesktopPeer.java:84)
at java.awt.Desktop.open(Desktop.java:272)
... 55 more
```

**update #2:** xdg-open works fine, opens the file mentioned in the stacktrace in LibreOffice Calc.

Answer (score 1):

Javadoc for
public: boolean [isSupported](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#isSupported-java.awt.Desktop.Action-)​(Desktop.Action action)

> > Even when the platform supports an action, a file or URI may not have a registered application for the action. For example, most of the platforms support the Desktop.Action.OPEN action. But for a specific file, there may not be an application registered to open it. In this case, isSupported(Action) may return true, but the corresponding action method will throw an IOException.

Comment: thanks  @Ashish! xdg-open works properly, does Desktop#open(java.io.File) using an other config file to get the registered application?

Comment: Not sure about it

Answer (score 0):

`desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.OPEN)` tells you that the plaform supports opening files, but there might not be an application registered to open a particular file, or the registered application might fail to open the file

Comment: thanks, then the problem might be that no application is registered for the file in the operating system? Btw, xdg-open works properly, opens the file mentioned in the stacktrace (I've just updated the question) with LibreOffice Calc.

Comment: It's hard for me to say but it sounds like the issue is more with your linux installation and its interaction with Java